# Remove wireframe lines from my textured cubes in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to remove the white wireframe lines from my 3D objects in Three.js, I tried with "overdraw:true" but it creates ugly cuts where were the lines.

This is the result:
http://i61.tinypic.com/2ilinvc.png

I also have a tessellated cube and the cuts are worse.

How can I have a textured cube without the wireframe lines and without the ugly cuts?

Comment: This is a fiddle (click to add/remove overdraw):
http://jsfiddle.net/V5aUC/1/

Comment: Sadly there is no solution for that yet.

Comment: @Julo `overdraw` takes a float, not a boolean now. See if `overdraw : 0.5` is better. three.js r.67